# Nightmare JS clicking a random link in a set

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, automation, nightmare

I can click on a link using:
`nightmare.click("#video-title")`
However that clicks the first element with that id.
When I run
`document.querySelectorAll('[id=video-title]')`
on a Youtube search, I get about 85 results. Is there a way to click a random one using Nightmare JS? Returning that list in a `evaluate` call does not work for me

`.evaluate(() => {
          return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id=video-title]'))
        })`

```
.then(videoLinks => {
      nightmare.click(videoLinks[0])
    })
```

Nightmare gives this error on the click:
`Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Object]' is not a valid selector.`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
.evaluate(() => {

     const list = document.querySelectorAll('[id=video-title]')
     return list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length)]

 })
```

In return it gives you random element from NodeList get by queryselectorAll

Comment: Please let me know if it works fine for you, i have tested it without nightmare context, but as i understand correctly evaluate function should return DOM element.